# Reverse of tf.parse_single_example

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a pipeline that takes as inputs tfrecords, applies some transformations and writes again to tfrecords.

I am using `tf.parse_single_example` to parse the single examples. This returns a dictionary of keys and tensors to which I apply the transformations.

I am not able to convert that dictionary back to a `tf.Example`. I wanted to do this by using

```
example = {some_key: tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[some_value]))
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=example))
```

but I think this was meant for numpy arrays as tf complains that it cannot iterate through tensors (`some_value` here) unless in eager mode.

Any idea how to inverte `tf.parse_single_example`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dataset` API of TensorFlow. You however have to do it slightly differently. Remember the following :

- TFRecord Writing does not require an instance of `tf.Session()`
- Parsing of TFRecords needs an instance of `tf.Session()`

The correct mechanism should be as follows :

```
import tensorflow as tf

def transform_fn(data):
    .......

def write2tfrecords(data, tf_writer):
    .....

db = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(file_list):
db = db.batch(batch_size)
db_iter = db.make_one_shot_iterator()
get_data = db_iter.get_next()

transformed_data = transform_fn(get_data)


init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

writer = .... # Initialize your TFRecordWriter here
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    sess.run(db_iter.initializer)
    while True:
        transformed = sess.run(transformed_data)
        write2tfrecords(transformed, writer)
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        break
```